# How to install and configure nova-lxd on existing openstack

Tags: networking, openstack, lxd, nova

I have installed openstack (Newton) on Ubuntu 16.04 on 4 Nodes, and I want to install and configure Nova-LXD, so that I can create and run a Linux Container using LXD. I am wondering whether anyone can tell me how to set this up, and is there any user guide for this?

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/05/06/introduction-to-nova-compute-lxd/) helps you. If you decide to use nova-lxd instead of kvm on your existing openstack you must run:

```
apt install nova-compute-lxd
```

This command automatically configure your nova-compute service. Then restart it, I hope it will work successfully.